# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError web service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, exception, command-prompt

I developed a web service in java that makes addition, subtraction, division and multiplication. Then, I created a class named `CallCalc` in another project named `CallCalculator`. I wrote some code in the class to call the web service. When I run the class `CallCalc` with parameters in eclipse, it returns to me the correct result, but when I run the class `CallCalc` with parameters in cmd, it throws an exception like;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com\example\ws\calculator\CalculatorSEI
at CallCalc.main<CallCalc.java:32>
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.ws.calculator.CalculatorSEI
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass<Unknown Source>
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass<Unknown Source>
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass<Unknown Source>
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass<Unknown Source>
... 1 more
```

I searched for a long time, tried different ways but could not correct it and I'm really confused. Maybe its answer is very simple, forgive me for that.

Does anybody have an idea about how to solve it? (I can post the necessary code block if you need)

Answer (score 0):

Is you project using maven? If so.. Do you have a dependency to the "SEI module" where CalculatorSEI is in?

A [NoClassDefFoundError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) occurs when you're using a class that is unknown at runtime hence you probably don't have a dependency to it.

Comment: No, I didn't use maven.

Comment: @TKsknl What do you build with? And does that other project have a dependency for the CalculatorSEI? Otherwise it can't use it.

Comment: I used Apache CXF. It is my first web service experience. Firstly, I created a wsdl file and then Generate Java Bean Skeleton from the wsdl file. All classes and interfaces appears automatically. Then, I added some code for return values of methods. I added web service project to my other project named CallCalculator on the build path to call the web service.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The second part does answer this question actually @UwePlonus. A NoClassDefFound always has something to do with unsatisfied dependencies.